# Как получить одинаковое значение из разных формат дат?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp

```js
console.log(new Date(2024, 5, 13).valueOf()) //1718226000000

console.log(String(1715592167).valueOf()) // ожидалось получить 1718226000000
```

Comment: **1715592167** = примерно13 Maя 2024.. почему при вызове `String(1715592167).valueOf()` должно выйти **1718226000000** не понимаю( последняя дата вообще июль выходит

Comment: А Вы же в курсе, что `(new Date(2024, 5, 13)` - это 13 **июня**?